# How to center and set wax-width with sliverGrid for flutter web

Tags: flutter

This is me getting introduced to flutter web and I have some close to this

```
Center(
  child: Container(
    constraints: BoxContaints(maxWidth: 700),
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverGrid(
          SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 1,
            mainAxisSpacing: 15,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10
          ),
          ...
        )
      ]
    )
  )
)
```

[image]
I can see where its coming from but now I don't even know How to center and set set a max width for the SliverList and still keep the global type scrollBall.

Comment: So the easy way to kinda fix this is by wrapping the SliverGrid/SliverList with Padding